# DVD Playback using Xubuntu

Tags: vlc, dvd

I have updated my software and installed VLC and installed the DVD Extras pack as suggested but the DVD will not play. I have tried several DVD's and reinstalled the Xubuntu from fresh and updated and upgraded but still no play I get the error message: GStreamer backend error: No valid frames found before end of stream. I have installed the codecs that came with the Extras pack and confirmed the license agreement. What have I missed....

Answer (score 0):

I searched for solutions to these error messages and found the answer here,  [that solved my issue with DVD's not playing](http://www.binarytides.com/better-xubuntu-14-04/) The page has some useful tips and tricks to solve many problems with your OS. I was instructed to open the terminal and cut and paste this text, sudo apt-get install libdvdread4, followed by, sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh, this has fixed the errors and now the DVD's play as the software installed decryption information to allow this.